# How fast is the blood flow in various vessels?

Tags: human-anatomy, human-physiology, blood-circulation

How fast is the blood flow in different blood vessels, such as the aorta and capillaries?

Comment: At rest, during sleep or in the midst of strenuous exercise? In human adults?

Comment: I didn't think the flow varied much between rest and high activity? A comparison would be nice. Yes, human adults.

Comment: You will have to account for mass balance using the Navier-Stokes equation which accounts for the cross-sectional area of the vessels.

Comment: @bobthejoe: Even with a good model of the arterial system, calculating these velocities through a model would probably not work. I'm looking for actual measurements, e.g. as those Larry posted for the MCA.

Answer (score 5):

In the middle cerebral artery blood flow at rest is 73.7 cm/s. After a period of 3 minutes of hyperventilation, blood flow in the same artery decreases to 37.6 cm/s. This is [published](http://www.ajnr.org/content/18/10/1929.full.pdf) work.

[Vena cava measures](http://circres.ahajournals.org/content/23/3/349.short): Peak velocities during ventricular systole ranged from 30 to 45 cm/sec in the inferior, and from 10 to 35 cm/sec in the superior, vena cava, also published.